# Redirecting SSL and Non-SSL to a different domain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

So, I could use a couple extra brain cells today, for the life of me I cannot figure out why this is not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

While the non-ssl redirects work fine, the ssl redirects do nothing...

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 rule for both http and https/www and non-www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `%{HTTPS} off [OR] %{HTTPS} on` = no test

Comment: Produces the same issue.  non-ssl redirects, while ssl does not